# How to load application.properties in a spring shell native app

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am working to build a spring shell native app with the graalvm. It compiles well enough but doesn't load the `applications.properties` file, which I sort-of understand since there is no more classpath. So, then, what's the acceptable way to do this? I was intending to keep passwords there.

For the record, I have tried putting `application.properties` right next to the native app.

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to use the application.properties from the resources package - try building the image with a resource-config, something of sort:

```
  {
  "pattern":"\\Qapplication.properties\\E"
  }
```

see docs : https://www.graalvm.org/22.1/reference-manual/native-image/Resources/

Comment: Those instructions sort-of work - it's based on the classpath, looks like. In my case, I need a runtime property file picked up in the local directory and this isn't accounted for here